# Css compilation issue on server

Tags: less, static-content, magento2.3.5-p2

My styles are not working with `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.
It is working only after running grunt commands.
Due to this my code is not working in server.
we are using Magento 2.3.5-p2.

Comment: Are you set to compile the css on the client side or server side?

Comment: it's server side.

Answer (score 0):

Please disable symlinks from the backend whose steps are given below.

```
Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Template Settings -> Allow Symlinks -> No -> Save Config.
```

After set **No** on admin. please run below commands succesfully after completed all command. check with hard refresh on browser.

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
**php bin/magento s:s:d -f**
**php bin/magento c:f**